# Java Exception (if a method returns false)

Tags: java, exception

Is there a way to catch an exception if a certain "validate" method returns a false?

I am validating certain values given to the object and I want to throw an exception and print out an error message (but continue the program) when the valdation (which is called via the constructor) fails so that the object will not be created.

Comment: What's wrong with `if(!certainValidateMethod()) throw new Exception();`?

Comment: Show us that code you mention. What you're asking now seems to generic to allow an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!validate())
    throw new Exception();
```